# Vaadin 14: Do service call before opening the File Upload Dialog

Tags: upload, vaadin, vaadin14

I have a page with an Upload file button, I want to do a service call when the user clicks and perform a check to determine if the file selection dialog should be shown to the user.
The file selection dialog SHOULD open only after the service call.

Something like this:

```
Button someButton = new Button("ClickMe");
someButton.addClickListener(event -> openDialogIfCheckSucceeds());
Upload fileUploadButton = new Upload();
fileUploadButton.setUploadButton(someButton);


void openDialogIfCheckSucceeds() {
    boolean someValue = /*Perform a service call*/
    if(someValue) {
        //Don't show file selection dialog, instead show a error dialog
    } else {
        //show file selection dialog so user can select files
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the call to the service call expensive? Why not do it on button creation and then enable/disable it according to the result of the service call?

Comment: The service call has a frequently changing status, hence between the time page loads and user clicks the button there might be a status change.

Comment: That dialog there is usually the one from OS or at least the browser. So instead of chasing a way to make that happening, I'd rather have two buttons - one that shows the error and the upload like now. Then decide beforehand, which one to show. Or why even bother to show a button - just tell the user, that uploads are not allowed for your reasons.